# How can I monitor if an external USB drive gets disconneted from a server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring, usb, hard-drive

I have a few servers that rely on external USB drives for some of their backup scripts.  However, there have been times when the USB drive might get disconnected accidentally (upon reboot or power outage or just anomalies).  This causes the backup script to fail to run.

Anybody know of a way to monitor if a drive is available and send an alert (SNMP, email, custom event log entry, doesn't matter) if it isn't available?  Something that polls on a regular basis (batch file, SNMP trap, etc.)

To keep this from being a "shopping question", I'm just curious what WMI or SNMP counters I can query against to find this information.

P.S.  I know I can monitor the backup script itself for failure, but that seems like the tail wagging the dog.  I'd rather know the external drive is down and fix it before the nightly backup runs.

Answer (score 3):

The [Win32_PnPEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx) class could be used to locate all USB devices attached to the system. I'd do a snapshot before and after device removal to find the specific instance to watch (something like `WMIC /namespace:\\ROOT\cimv2 PATH Win32_PnPEntity GET` output to a text file).